# Ansible Tower: How to launch multiple jobs from same template parallel

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

I have a project in Ansible Tower, and a template derived from the project. I am running a job with this template against a host (Say a.example.com) . Now I want to run a job with this template at the same time against another (Say b.example.com).

How do I achieve this? Currently the second job waits for the first job to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Look at "Job Concurrency" in the Ansible tower documentation. The number of concurrent jobs depend on your servers capacity. 
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/jobs.html

Comment: There is no  "Job Concurrency" at this link.

Comment: Looks like the recent document do not use the term Job Concurrency. It is under capacity job section.